# Get last visible element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
    <tr class="here" id="t1" number="1" ><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr class="here" id="t2" number="2" ><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr class="here" id="t3" number="3" style="display:none"><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr class="here" id="t4" number="4" style="display:none"><td>4</td></tr>
</table>

<span id="check">check</span>

$('#check').click(function(){        
    check = ???;
   alert(check);
})
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vUukc/1/

How can I get the attribute `number` from last visible `tr` in this example? This is an example - all `<tr>` could be visible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are different  [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for those purposes.

**For example:**

```
$('table tr:visible:last').attr('number');
```

or

```
$('table tr:visible').last().attr('number');
```

and so on.

**Full code**

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    check = $('table tr:visible:last').attr('number');
    alert(check);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vUukc/4/)**

Answer (score 5):

```
$("table tr:visible:last").attr("number");
```

See the [jQuery Documentation on Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more info on the `:visible` and `:last` selectors.

Comment: @merv Right, thanks for adding the link :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vUukc/11/)**

```
   $('#check').click(function(){

    alert($('table').find('tr:visible:last').attr("number"));

   })​;
```

​